# C# Out of Range in For Loop

Tags: c#

I'm running this code, but every time, I get the error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred" on the first line of the for loop. Its basically code for a multiple choice quiz question, with questions & answers stored in a 2d array.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to spot the problem. It's probably a simple error, but I'm a beginner so I'm struggling to spot it.

I've read through similar questions, but I don't understand why this line is causing problems. I've got 4 elements in my list, one is removed before the loop, so there should be 3 left. I'm only looping through 3 times, so I don't understand what the problem is.

Hopefully someone will be able to help, Thanks!

```
     Random rndq = new Random();
     Random rnda = new Random();
     List<int> answers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

     int questionchoice = rndq.Next(0, questions.GetLength(0) - 1);
     int labelchoice = rnda.Next(0, answers.Count-1);
     lblQuestion.Text = questions[questionchoice, 0];
     var answer = (Label)Controls["lblAns" + answers[labelchoice]];
     answer.Text = questions[questionchoice, 1];

     answers.Remove(labelchoice);

     int j = 2;
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     {
         var wronganswers = (Label)Controls["lblAns" + answers[i]];
         wronganswers.Text = questions[questionchoice, j];
         answers.RemoveAt(i);
         j++;
     }
```

Comment: `answers[i]` ... `answers.RemoveAt(i)`

Comment: There are reasons why loops that remove are usually backwards, this is one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each pass through the loop you're removing an item from the list.  After the first pass your list has 3 items in it `[2, 3, 4]`.  Next pass there are two items left `[2, 4]`.  Then you try to get the third item from the list of two and get an exception.

Either you need to leave the list alone while looping or make sure that your loop condition actually references the length of the list.  Assuming that you want to actually process all 4 items I would suggest that you remove the `RemoveAt` call completely.

Or if you actually want to remove the items, reverse the direction of your loop:

```
for (int i = answers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    // ....
    answers.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

This will still process all of the items in the list and leave you with nothing in the list at the end.

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer